# Keeping value inside input form after submit

Tags: javascript, symfony, input

I have a small html form in my twig that helps me to filter results, and I would like when the user add a value as an example `foo` and submit, it keeps the value he/she just entered after the page refresh.

I have been searching and couldn't find thing that would make it work, or I'm doing this really badly.
My only soltution is now to do it in JS.

I will show you my code

**my form in my twig**

```
<form action="{{ path('st_backoffice_commerce_offre') }}" method="get">
       <input name="filter" type="text" value="" id=userInput">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Filtrer</button>
</form>
```

**my controller where I setup the `filter` variable**

```
private function resultsAction(Request $request, User $user, $type, $archive)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
        $filter = $request->query->get('filter');

        $qb = $em->getRepository("STUserBundle:Operation")->getQueryByTypeAndPro($type, $user, $archive, $filter);

        $results = $paginator->paginate(
            $qb,
            $request->query->get('page',1),
            $request->query->get('limit',50),
            [
                'defaultSortFieldName'      => 'opn.dateCreation',
                'defaultSortDirection' => 'desc'
            ]
        );

        return array("results" => $results, "archive" => $archive);
    }

public function offreAction(Request $request, User $user, $archive = false)
    {
        return $this->resultsAction($request, $user, Operation::OFFRE_COMMERCIALE, $archive);
    }
```

**and the JS code I have found to try to make that work**

```
var $userInput;
    $("filter").on("change", function(){
        $userInput = $("filter").val();
    });
```

I tried as well PHP code into twig but....it wasn't a good idea as I could not make it work.
So i'm stuck with a rather simple question I had, but couldn't really achieve my input to stay after refresh in twig.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the request object by twig according the documentation : https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#app

So maybe you can try this :

```
<input name="filter" type="text" value="{{ app.request.query.get('filter') }}" id=userInput">
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer :) it works perfectly. Actually with your method I don't even need the JS